# Gstreamer: Save image/jpeg using multifilesink every 5 seconds

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I am trying to figure out how to save an image using multifilesink every N seconds (lets say 5). My get-launch-1.0 pipeline is below: `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! 'video/x-raw, format=I420, width=400, height=400, framerate=1/5' ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=/some/location/img_%06d.jpg`

I was thinking the framerate option could control the capture speed but it seems to not be affecting anything. How can I delay this pipeline to only save a jpeg every N seconds?

Edit: So I figured how that this will work with videotestsrc if you set "is-live=true" but I would like to do this with an nvcamerasrc or nvarguscamerasrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the videotestsrc is not running as a live source, it will pump out frames as fast as it can, updating timestamps based on the output framerate configured on the source pad.
Setting it to live-mode will ensure that it actually matches the expected framerate.
This shouldn't be an issue with a true live source like a camera source.

However something like this can force synchronization with the videotestsrc:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, format=I420, width=400, height=400, framerate=1/5 ! identity sync=true ! timeoverlay ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location="/some/location/img_%06.jpg"
```